# while(past, past continuous), what's the difference?

Tags: time

I'm learning the word, 'while'.

1. While she waited, he mended her shoes.
2. While she was waiting, he mended her shoes

Is there a difference?

thanks :)

Answer (score 4):

(1) would usually imply that she was waiting *for* the shoes to be mended, perhaps so that she could put them on again afterwards.

(2) could mean that she was waiting for something else, and at some point during that time she got her shoes mended.

Answer (score 1):

'waited' means the whole process of the 'mending',and 'was waiting' means the state in which she was 'in the middle' of the 'mending'. The use varies by the situations.

BUT, apart from the second sentence, This kind of sentenses can also indicate a situation where the the verb of the main clause interrupted or occurred as if it had interrupted the verb of the subordinate clause if the 'main verb' occurs in a very short time.

Hope I helped, and glad to see my own kind on a foreign website.